# How to avoid clearing canvas element on changing it's container's innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, innerhtml

I am using javascript to draw to a canvas element inside a div, contained within a wrapper. 
The canvas and its div are generated dynamically by adding to the wrapper's innerHTML.
The goal is to allow an infinite number of canvases to be generated

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="container"><canvas id="previous"></canvas></div>
     <!-- infinite # of container divs & canvases -->
</div>
```

However, when I add a new div and canvas to the wrapper's innerHTML anything drawn to the previous canvas is lost.

Where if I add a new canvas elsewhere on the page, to a div outside of the container, or a child of the container:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="container"><canvas id="previous"></canvas></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2">
     <!-- newly inserted canvas: -->
     <div id="container"><canvas></canvas></div>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="container"><canvas id="previous"></canvas></div>
     <div id="wrapperChild">
          <!-- newly inserted canvas: -->
          <div id="container"><canvas></canvas></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then the previous canvas is preserved.

From what I can tell changing the innerHTML of the wrapper or it's parents results in clearing the canvas. Any advice on how I can avoid clearing the canvas? Can I preserve what's been drawn to the canvas elsewhere and restore it?

Comment: Does using DOM instead of `innerHTML` clear the canvases? I mean, you could draw the current canvas to a temporary canvas and then draw it back, but that's hardly feasible with a number of canvases. `innerHTML` requires a restructuring of the current nodes, which might be the reason for clearing of the canvases. If you can, use DOM and avoid `innerHTML`.

Comment: Another possible approach is insertAdjacentHtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of your javascript approach (jQuery, something else, or nothing), you can do this by not using innerHTML. Basically, when you append to the innerHTML property, you're saying "take the value of innerHTML, add it to this new value (the canvas element, perhaps), then set innerHTML to all of that. In other words, you aren't really appending "in place". You're basically adding a fresh version of everything you have, and since the canvas isn't drawing its contents with child elements, they aren't going to be brought over with this method.

Instead of using innerHTML, you should be working with the DOM, appending children to the parent as nodes instead of strings.

Comment: Thanks very much. I don't have a lot of experience with using DOM, but when you explain it like that I can see the flaw of using innerHTML. 

I'll try implementing into my project, but a quick test shows that appending children is the way to go.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. It's these incremental experiences that help us learn. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is a good use case for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Using jquery, you can append a `<canvas>` element into an arbitrary container, and avoid having to interact with "innerHtml".

For example:

```
var myCanvas = $("<canvas>").appendTo("#container");
```

What this does is add a new `<canvas>` element to the element whose id is "container" (your div). The "#" is a css selector for ids. Google "css selectors", since that's a pretty broad topic.

The `myCanvas` variable is now a jQuery array containing a reference to the canvas you just added. `myCanvas[0]` will be the actual DOM element that you can interact with.

Using this approach, you will never need to change the "innerHtml" of your div, and so the existing canvases will never be touched/cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using innerHtml, use appendChild:

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(NewNodeHere);
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out Simon's tutorial on drawing shapes.
http://simonsarris.com/project/canvasdemo/shapes.html

All the properties and position of the shapes are stored within an object array.
When an event occurs like (click on shape) the state of the canvas changes (in this case a shape is being dragged) and for each change of the mouse position the canvas is redrawn using the new coordinates and properties.

Now if you also use shapes, images, text objects you can store their properties in object arrays too. This way you can draw the same shapes on multiple canvases in the same manner just by iterating through the arrays multiple times.

Therefore, when you add a new canvas dynamically, you can simply redraw the previous context.

this is the relevant code from Simon's tutorial:

You define a rectangle shape (constructor)

```
function Shape(x, y, w, h, fill) {
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
  this.w = w || 1;
  this.h = h || 1;
  this.fill = fill || '#AAAAAA';
}
```

Draw this shape to a given context
    Shape.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
       ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
       ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }

Add new shapes to array

```
CanvasState.prototype.addShape = function(shape) {
  this.shapes.push(shape);
  this.valid = false;
}
```

Iterate through array and draw all shapes correspondingly

```
var l = shapes.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  var shape = shapes[i];
  // We can skip the drawing of elements that have moved off the screen:
  if (shape.x > this.width || shape.y > this.height ||
      shape.x + shape.w < 0 || shape.y + shape.h < 0) continue;
  shapes[i].draw(ctx);
}
```